# why is it giving output vertically

Tags: java

```
public class TrianglePatterns {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i, j, row = 5;
        for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.println("* ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
* 

* 
* 

* 
* 
* 

* 
* 
* 
* 

* 
* 
* 
* 
*
```

Comment: Because you're using `println`, that puts a newline after every output. Try with `print` in the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using [`println`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#print-java.lang.String-) (read "PRINT LinNe"), that puts a newline after every output:

> Prints a String and then **terminates the line**. This method behaves as though it invokes `print(String)` and then `println()`.

As [commented by Federico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71076453/why-is-it-giving-output-vertically#comment125644773_71076453).

And because you're printing **in each iteration** of your for-loop.

#### How To Print horizontally (in one line)

Use [`print`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println-java.lang.String-) (the method without `ln`) instead

```java
        int i, j, row = 5;
        for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print("* ");  // print within a single line
            }
            System.out.println();  // terminating the line with a line-break
        }
```

It prints the expected **5 rows** plus a final line-break without content in the new line (because loop ends):

```
* 
* * 
* * * 
* * * * 
* * * * *
```

Try it on `jshell`:

```
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 17.0.2
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell>         int i, j, row = 5;
   ...>         for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
   ...>             for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
   ...>                 System.out.print("* ");  // print within a single line
   ...>             }
   ...>             System.out.println();  // terminating the line with a line-break
   ...>         }
   ...> 
i ==> 0
j ==> 0
row ==> 5
* 
* * 
* * * 
* * * * 
* * * * * 

jshell>
```